# Can I tell TypeScript document.head may be null?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript's DOM type declarations, `document.head` is defined as

```
readonly head: HTMLHeadElement;
```

But there are some edge cases where it is `null` or doesn't exist:

https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4565#issuecomment-533877335

> Heh. I actually found a case where document.head can be null due to running early: Browser extensions / WebExtensions.
>
> Content scripts specified to run at document_start are actually run before document.head exists, both in Chrome and Firefox. (But document.documentElement still seems to be non-null, though.)

and I'm writing code which runs in that context. I tried to change the declaration in this way

```
declare global {
  interface Document {
    readonly head?: HTMLHeadElement | null;
  }
}
```

but this gives an error:

```
../../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:6859:14 - error TS2687: All declarations of 'head' must have identical modifiers.

6859     readonly head: HTMLHeadElement;
                  ~~~~

index.d.ts:35:14 - error TS2687: All declarations of 'head' must have identical modifiers.

35     readonly head?: HTMLHeadElement | null;
                ~~~~

index.d.ts:35:14 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'head' must be of type 'HTMLHeadElement', but here 
has type 'HTMLHeadElement | null | undefined'.

35     readonly head?: HTMLHeadElement | null;
                ~~~~

  ../../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:6859:14
    6859     readonly head: HTMLHeadElement;
                      ~~~~
    'head' was also declared here.
```

which makes sense. I've also tried re-declaring global `var window` with the modified type, but also unsuccessfully.

Comment: As far as I know you can't merge in a change like this and you'd probably need to use your own local copy of the DOM declaration file(s) instead of the TS-provided one(s).  If you're only doing this in one place (or a few places) in your code I'd probably just use a type assertion `as HTMLHeadElement | null` at the use site or sites.  Either way it seems like a mess.  I'd write this up as an answer but "nope" is not very exciting.  I'll wait to see if anyone else has a clever workaround.